# issue with jquery .post() not working

Tags: php, jquery, .post

so I am new to using jquery .post() however I am not using methods i haven't already used before.

I am trying to post two hidden input values when a button is clicked:

```
$('#button').live('click', function() {
    $.post('export_file.php', { group: form.group.value , test: form.test.value },
    function(output)    {
        $('#return').html(output).show();
    });
});
```

i have tested the button event is firing successfully and currently all I trying to do in `export_file.php` is echo something.

here is my form:

```
<form name="form">
<input type="hidden" name="group" value="<?echo $group;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?echo $test_id;?>">
<input type="button" class="Mybutton" id="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Export Results">
</form>
```

i have got my div on the original page:

`<div id='return'></div>`

export_file.php:

```
<?php

echo "whatever, something!";

?>
```

Could anyone point out where I am going wrong. Many thanks,

Comment: What does Firebug console tell you? Any JS error?

Comment: see demo i added in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix this line:

```
$.post('export_file.php', { group: form.group.value , test: form.test.value },
```

Change it to something like this:

```
var group_val = $('input[name="group"]', 'form[name="form"]').get(0).value;
var test_val = $('input[name="test"]', 'form[name="form"]').get(0).value;
$.post('export_file.php', { group: group_val , test: test_val },
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/cQ2vZ/

Comment: @downVoter anyone want to explain it?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$('#button').live('click', function() {
    $.post('export_file.php', { group: $("input[name='group']").val() , test: $("input[name='test']").val() },
    function(output)    {
        $('#return').html(output).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: that would make it apply to **any** input with the `name=test` and any one with the `name=group`

Comment: @Neal: And his current form only has one.  C'mon, why does this have to be so overly complex?  Don't assume requirements that aren't there.

Comment: @mellamokb i code to what i believe the OP will do in the future.

Comment: @Neal, in that case why haven't you validated the input for him as well? Why haven't you added in an autocomplete function as well?

Comment: In fact, why haven't you also coded a small plugin for him that will ajaxsubmit any form he likes using serialized form data? I mean you surely "believe" that he'll want to submit a form via AJAX in the future, no?

Answer (score 1):

I've added ids to your form elements in your HTML:

```
<form name="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="group" id="group" value="<?echo $group;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="<?echo $test_id;?>">
    <input type="button" class="Mybutton" id="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Export Results">
</form>
```

Then amended the jQuery to get the values from these fields by ID, and use these in the parameters of your AJAX call:

```
$('#button').live('click', function() {
    var groupValue = $("#group").val();
    var testValue = $("#test").val();

    $.post('export_file.php', { group: groupValue , test: testValue },
    function(output)    {
        $('#return').html(output).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: They do not need ids, see my answer below

Comment: you are missing `.val()` in assignments: `var groupValue = $("#group").val();`

Comment: You mean your answer above :P

Comment: @Neal all respect, your answer was overly complex, there's pretty much no need to set variables in such a simple case

Comment: @Neal, true they do not need ids to work, but the Id selector is by far the quickest, so I always suggest people use that when possible, rather than `INPUT[name=foo]`. At the end of the day they all work, it's just personal preference.

Comment: thanks this works, could I ask, why did mine not work in this case? i got it from a tutorial, and worked previously for me?

Comment: @BenStephenson this user also used variables :-P

Comment: @buymypies In plain javascript you can get the value of a field by using `document.formName.fieldName.value`, or `document.forms[index].fieldName.value`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$('#button').live('click', function() {
    var group_val = $("input[name='group']").val(); // gets the value of hidden field with the name group
    var test_val = $("input[name='test']").val(); // gets the value of hidden field with the name test and store it in test_val variable
    $.post('export_file.php', { group: group_val  , test: test_val  },
    function(output)    {
        $('#return').html(output).show();
    });
});
```